# Tengo 2 errores en mi codigo de Visual Studio, CS0102 y CS0229 respectivamente este ultimo repitiéndose varias veces en el diseño, como los arreglo?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int Velocidad = 8;
    int Gravedad = 15;
    int PUNTAJENUM = 0;

    public Form1()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EVENTO1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GAMEOVERPANTALLA.Hide();
        PAJARO.Top += Gravedad;
        TUBERIA_ABAJO.Left -= Velocidad;
        TUBERIA_ARRIBA.Left -= Velocidad;

        if (TUBERIA_ABAJO.Left < -150)
        {
            TUBERIA_ABAJO.Left = 700;
            PUNTAJENUM++; 
        }

        if (TUBERIA_ARRIBA.Left < -180)
        {
            TUBERIA_ARRIBA.Left = 850;
            PUNTAJENUM++; +ERROR
        }
```

> Especifica que problemas de ambigüedad y que "PUNTAJENUM" ya esta definido
> La verdad no he intentado muchas cosas, esto se debe a la escasa información que encontré online en cuanto a esta que fuera similar a mi caso

Comment: PUNTAJENUM ya esta definido es porque lo estas volviendo a definir otra  vez. tenes el codigo incompleto entonces no se ve donde lo estas volviendo a definir. y Lo mismo te sucede con la ambiguedad, seguramente estas heredando algo que ya tiene esa propiedad creada.

Comment: Pero, detras de esa parte de codigo solo esta el namespace, los using y ya, no se ha declarado antes.

Comment: El visual te señála donde esta sucediendo eso. no digo que sea para arriba o para abajo puede ser otra clase.